# Is Bluetooth's BD_ADDR a unique identifier?

Tags: network

In the course of building a system controller: the context is that users have a modern Bluetooth smartphone with the Bluetooth on.  I suspect that BT is broadcasting a unique identifier: a raspberry pi could detect said BT identifier and execute an a control algorithm.

Is BD_ADDR a unique identifier?  Is there any other BT identifier that can be used?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth uses the same MAC address space as e.g. Ethernet and Wi-Fi, maintained by IEEE. MAC addresses are allocated to a vendor by OUI (first 24 bits) and the vendor allocates the other 24 bits.

While you can use the MAC address to distinguish nodes, you need to keep in mind that they are publicly visible and they can be forged very easily. Don't use them for anything security related.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth employs address randomization to increase user privacy.  Here are a few good Stack Exchange threads related to it.  In short, **Bluetooth addresses are not assured to be unique** under some circumstances.

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/200474/mac-randomization-for-bluetooth
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471364/private-vs-public-addresses-in-bluetooth-low-energy-on-android